# Samsung CLP 325 colour laser printer fault

Tags: printer, colors

I have a Samsung CLP 325 laser colour printer, some years' old. It prints perfectly in black only. In fact, I have just bought three toner cartridges, one of which was 'K' (black) and the mono printout is really excellent. When I print in colour, however, the following happens (1) a second image of the print-out appears on the page and (2) the printer throws coloured toner (mainly cyan and magenta) all over the page, creating a dirty background and vertical streaks. It seems so puzzling. What is wrong?

Tom Sharp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Printing in monochrome (black toner only) is perfect. If I print in colour, however, the image is repeated further down the page. The page is additionally almost completel;y covered with a smattering of toner. It looks as if it is the cyan and magenta colours.

Comment: The toner is not fusing properly. When printing colour, do you use the same paper as for mono? If not, you need to tell the print5er what it is so it can adjust the fuser temperature.